# Random error 500 "The ConnectionString property has not been initialized"

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, windows-server-2008-r2

I've been using the same ConnectionString since our site got online on July 2010, and never had any problem to connect and interact with our database.
However, since July 2011, I keep getting random "The ConnectionString property has not been initialized" errors.

- **How does the bug happen?**

Our site runs fine during a variable time period (from a few hours to a few weeks, although I noted that today it is more a few hours), meaning queries with database work fine, people can login, etc.. And then, at some point, connectionString error just happens.
From this moment, our site becomes inaccessible, and keeps returning this error for whatever page we try to access.
Sometimes, after 10-15mn, our site gets back online itself, and runs fine until the error pops up again. But most of the time, I have to use one of the 3 following methods to make it work again :

1) Saving Web Config file again, without adding/changing anything
2) Stopping and starting site in IIS
3) Rebooting the server

There is on our server the development site too. However, it **never** threw me this random error. The only differences between our development site and production site are different databases, sql users and authentification modes in Web Config (production = Windows, development = forms)

- **What has changed since July 2010 on our server?**

.net framework was upgraded from 3.5 to 4 on March 2011.
The site physical directory has been moved from the original IIS directory to another partition on the same server since June 2011 (basically, just a cut/paste of the site directory and a change of application physical path in IIS).
Windows Server 2008 updates are applied everytime there are some.

- **What did I try to fix this?**

1) First thing, I tried to put back our site directory into IIS inetpub/wwwroot again. It didn't change anything.
2) I tried to put the same directory permissions on our production site as on our development site. Still nothing.
3) I compared the two application pools development/production, but there aren't any differences.
4) And of course, I've searched on numerous sites to find if someone's ever come across this issue too. The most related topic to my problem I found is this one :
[Web.config - ConnectionString property has not been initialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827035/web-config-connectionstring-property-has-not-been-initialized)
However, I don't understand how I can check for "randomly applied permissions across my web root folder".

- **Stack Trace on home page when error occurrs** :

```
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.PermissionDemand()  
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)  
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()  
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)  
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)  
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet)  
at Database.listeCategories(enuTypeCategorie typeCategorie, enuOrdre ordre, enuActif actif, Boolean withFirstRow, Boolean libTous)  
at user_controls_criteresAnnonce.set_secteur(Int32 value)  
at user_controls_criteresAnnonce.initValues()  
at _default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs a)  
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()  
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Since the error concerns any page when it pops up, the source is always different.

- **System information** :

The sites (development and production) are running on Windows Server 2008 SP2 with IIS 7.
Database runs under SQL Server 2005.
.NET framework is 4 (ASP version written in Server manager : ASP.NET 4.0.30319.0).

ConnectionString is stored in Web Config file with the following pattern :

```xml
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="BosstobossDbBase" connectionString="Server=server_ip; Database=database_name; User=login; password=pass" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

And before any database connection attempt, connectionString is affected to a SqlConnection object like this (conn is declared in a class) :

```vb
conn = New SqlConnection()
conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("BosstobossDbBase").ConnectionString  
conn.Open()
```

If you need further information, please don't hesitate to ask me. I'm at a loss with this... Any help would be gladly accepted.
Thank you!

Best regards,
Kevin

Comment: Do you have calls to ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("BosstobossDbBase").ConnectionString scattered all throughout your code? Or have you encapsulated it?

Comment: FYI saving the web.config file is causing the application pool to recycle. Do you have memory capacity issues?

Answer (score 0):

I'd change the web.config file to this and see if it helps:

```
 <connectionStrings> 
     <remove name="BosstobossDbBase" />
     <add name="BosstobossDbBase" connectionString="Server=server_ip; Database=database_name;User=login; password=pass" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/> 
 </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to try this and get back to you if the problem still persists.

Comment: Too bad, connectionString error still happened during the night with the same behaviour (site worked for a few hours, and then it becomes inaccessible until I do one of the 3 methods described in my post) :(

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this same problem for a long time.
I had a application on ASP.Net v2.0 which had been working normally and suddenly one day I started getting this error.

I resolved it in the following way:

Open inetmgr and click on the main server.
In the Features View, click on ConnectionStrings.
In my case there were two connection strings which were inherited by all the applications.
It turned out one of the strings was invalid and when I deleted it, everything was back to normal.

One of the users on that machine had added that string some time back which broke all the applications.

Hope this helps.